# Design factory for Java driver

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I would like to create Factory class which returns Object based on String variable. For example:

```
public class BrowserFactory
{
    public BrowserFactory(String browser)
    {
        switch (browser.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "chrome":
            {
                new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            }
            case "firefox":
            {
                new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            }
            case "explorer":
            {
                new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            }
            case "edge":
            {
                new EdgeDriver();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use it this way:

```
BrowserFactory sd = new BrowserFactory("chrome");
```

Can you propose some better way to design this code?

Comment: Think you should read aboud factory design again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory should Looks like this:

```
public class BrowserFactory
{
    private BrowserFactory(){
    }
    public static RemoteWebDriver getDriver(String browser)
    {
        switch (browser.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "chrome":
            {
                return new ChromeDriver();
            }
            case "firefox":
            {
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            case "explorer":
            {
                return new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
            case "edge":
            {
                return new EdgeDriver();
            }
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Browser not supported")

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And you call it:

```
RemoteDriver rd = BrowserFactory.getDriver("chrome");
```